# Removing even elements from a list in Prolog using accumulator method

Tags: prolog

I am trying to write a program that removes even elements from a list in prolog in a relatively elegant way. My idea was to use an accumulator. That is, I have a list that starts empty and gradually builds the list up by chopping off even elements. To give some intuition, I'm inspired by the following program for reversing the elements of a list:

```
accRev([],A,A).
accRev([H|T],A,R) :- accRev(T,[H|A],R).
```

Now my idea was the following:

```
without_even([],A,A).
without_even([H|T],A,N) :-
    H mod 2 =\= 0,
    without_even(T,[H|A],N).
```

We begin by passing an empty list to A. So, the idea is that we want the list N such that N = A where A is the result of going through [H|T] and chopping all the even heads off. But When I test this with

```
?- without_even([1,2],[],N).
```

I get false. I wonder if anyone can help with the intuition here – I am two days into using Prolog – so that I can work towards a solution.

My intuition tells me that I need another clause for the case when the head is even.

**EDIT**:

I have managed to get it to work with the following program:

```
without_even([],A,A).
without_even([H|T],A,N) :- 
    H mod 2 =\= 0, without_even(T,[H|A],N).
without_even([H|T],A,N) :-
    H mod 2 =:= 0, without_even(T,A,N).
```

Comment: Example: https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=include/3

Comment: Doesn't that reverse the order of the elements? Why use accumulator if you don't need it?

Comment: That `without_even` only needs 3 arguments, rather than 2, if it is *intended* to reverse the order.

Comment: It's not intended to reverse the order, but yes, I guess it does. I was just wanting a more efficient solution than the one suggested in what I was reading, which was many lines long

Answer (score 1):

To remove even numbers, it's just:

```
remove_even( []     , []     ) .
remove_even( [X|Xs] ,    Ys  ) :- X rem 2 =:= 0, !, remove_even(Xs,Ys) .
remove_even( [X|Xs] , [X|Ys] ) :-                   remove_even(Xs,Ys) .
```

Or even more elegantly:

```
remove_even( Xs , Ys ) :- findall( X , ( member(X,Xs), X rem 2 =\= 0 ), Ys ).
```

Comment: Still not as elegant as the example at https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=include/3

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
remove_even([], []).
remove_even([X|Xs], Zs) :-
    R is X mod 2,
    remove_even_case(R, X, Ys, Zs),
    remove_even(Xs, Ys).
 
remove_even_case(0, X, Ys, [X|Ys]).   
remove_even_case(1, _, Ys, Ys).
```